# Rails 3.0.12 translation file won't parse with "couldn't parse YAML at line 1 column 0"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, yaml, language-translation

I believe I have a valid yml translation file that won't parse because of a special character.   For an example "switchfrench: 'Français'" fails to load with the error, couldn't parse YAML at line 1 column 0.  The yml file "switchfrench: 'Francais'" loads correctly.

https://gist.github.com/2415270

Any ideas on how to get this to parse?

Comment: What does File.read('config/locales/app.fr.yml') give you?  Perhaps better yet: Rails.root.read('config/locales/app.fr.yml')

Comment: I updated https://gist.github.com/2415270.  File.read reads the file correctly but Rails.root.read raises "TypeError: can't convert String into Integer"

Comment: Ah, doh, I meant to say Rails.root.join('config/locales/app.fr.yml').read

Comment: that reads the file correctly

Comment: looks like the read adds an escaped char that won't parse: YAML.parse( "switchfrench: Fran\xE7ais\n" )

Comment: I was seeing that in the my console, though I had forgotten where I got it ;)  Does writing it via the console below help?  If I do puts "switchfrench: Fran\xE7ais\n" I end up with 'switchfrench: Fran?ais', so I don't think that is the right character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this works:

```
1.9.3p125 :008 > YAML.load("switchfrench: Français\n")
 => {"switchfrench"=>"Français"}
```

What if you tried writing that to disk from the console, like this:

```
File.open('config/locales/app.fr.yml', 'w') {|f| f << "switchfrench: Français\n" }
```